# Would you be able to shoot a metal collar off?

Tags: science-fiction, weapons, escape

Say one of your characters have a metal collar attached. One that acts like a tracker and an alarm if they manage to escape their cell. If they get their hands on a gun, would they be able to aim it in a way that they could shoot it off/damage it to the point where it stops working without killing/severely injuring yourself? If yes, what type of gun and how would they avoid injury? If not, what would be a good way to get it off with the limited resources of a prisoner. The guards nearby do not have the key to the collars. Similarly, would some sort of blade be able to stab or cut through it? There’s quite a bit of far fetched tech and abilities in this world, so feel free to be creative.

Comment: All this really depends on your collar's design.

Comment: What John said. Also, how tamper-resistant are these collars? Do they alarm anyway (or kill the wearer) if someone tried to mess with them?

Comment: Yes,  the collar will attempt to shock the wearer if tampered with. But I’m not too worried about this part as my character is immune to being electrocuted. Most of the sensitive parts of the collar is protected on the inside, and the rest is durable metal like material. There’s a part around the centre of the collar that does glow, and at the back is similar to a keypad screen for a password to be entered. If the keypad is not used then a remote is used to unlock the collar.

Comment: It looks like you've already build your world and are asking how events in your world will play out.

Comment: So there's a locking mechanism and it can be unlocked by remote or password, which implies their will be a way to attack it by locking.  You'd be surprised how many sophisticated locks can be by-passed relatively simply.  Shooting it off seems a bit dangerous as a first (second or third) option.  You'd need to be desperate.

Comment: The best collars I've seen are in *The Reefs of Space* (1964). The collars are explosive, booby-trapped, deadman-timered, remote-triggerable by multiple methods (including broadcast), obvious to everybody, and can be unlocked only by one entity on the entire planet. They simply cannot be removed without killing the wearer -- one protagonist must have his head surgically removed and re-attached to get out of the collar.

Answer (score 2):

**Cut the antenna.**

The idea of shooting the collar off is great for a fiction: great to have some half-smart character propose.  There are so many ways that can go wrong.  You characters can discuss them.

The metal collar will be tough.  But it has integral electronics - it must have an antenna because it can track him and transmit a signal.  It must have a power source.  Maybe the power source is built into the collar but the antenna is probably on the inner face of the collar or along one edge.

Use a rock or a piece of the gun to rub through the antenna.  Or the connection to the battery if that is more accessible.  Whomever is watching that antenna will see the signal drop.  That person will send a guard to check on the prisoner, who he will find in the cell.  Then a guard will come with a new collar and keys to remove the old collar.  That is when the gun comes in handy.

Alternatively, if you disable the antenna and leave the collar on you can at least escape and not be tracked.

Later on you can have the prisoner get shot in the neck during a firefight.  The bullet bounces off the collar which is unbroken but which leaves a huge bruise on the prisoners neck.  The half-smart character shrugs; "guess you were right about that!".

Comment: If the designers aren't idiots, and are at all worried about this sort of thing (and they should be, just for the sake of normal wear and tear!), the collar will be made of a durable but radio-transparent material with all the sensitive bits inside. We build [similar devices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smartphone) (from a durability and electronics capabilities standpoint, anyway) already in real life. For that matter, even a cheap plastic housing will make it fairly damage-resistant.

Comment: Attempting to damage the collar puts you in direct opposition to the designer's primary focus, the collar's durability against the kinds of damage which prisoners are likely to do to it.  A better approach would be to wrap the collar (and prisoner) in a faraday's cage which would block its signal and summons the soon-to-be-shot guard.  Alternatively, exposing the collar to a strong magnetic field might erase any solid state memory and cause it to fail enough to summons the guard.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to file it off; all you need is a big enough file and enough time and patience. You could also use an angle grinder,  which would be spectacular but not recommended on health and safety grounds.

Shooting off a metal collar would be like trying to shoot something stuck between your teeth: even if it works, the side effects would probably be undesirable.